# Nodemailer to GMAIL Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

It is a GMAIL server my two-step password is correct and my recipient data is correct

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {
  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
  //let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com", //Servidor de gmail
  port: 465, //Puerto de servidor de gmail
  secure: true, //Esta activado en true // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
  user: ' ****@gmail.com',/*testAccount.user,*/ // generated ethereal user
  pass: 'qskafnvgyhzyrceb'/*testAccount.pass,*/ // generated ethereal password
},
```

});

```
// send mail with defined transport object
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
from: '*****@gmail.com',/*'"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>',*/ // sender address
to: '*****@gmail.com',/*"bar@example.com, baz@example.com",*/ // list of receivers
subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
html: "<h1>Hello World</h1>", // html body
});
}

main().then(() => { console.log('Correo Enviado') }).catch((err)=>{ console.log(err) }/*console.error*/);`
```

but I have this error

```
Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
  at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1538:34)
  at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
  at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:952:8)
  at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:733:12) {
   code: 'ESOCKET',
   command: 'CONN'
}
```

I want send any email to gmail acount,

this code worked for me last week